# Enabling search for my site that uses rss

Tags: search, rss

my site is [here](http://bfcards.edicypages.com/)

The main flash app uses rss (or xml) to display data. I'm wondering how I can add search functionality to it. One idea is to create multiple custom rss for each filter and search query, but I thought that it would be a nightmare to add more data later on. So I'm wondering if there's another way to do it?

RSS feed is located [here](http://rssfeed.ucoz.com/rssfeed.xml) My site is hosted at edicy.com and I can't install any other server side extensions other than use XHTML, XML, HTML and Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Index your data using a search engine like solr or sphinx then have your flash app talk to the server to post a query to it and retrieve the results in XML

Comment: @Wes Thanks, checking these two out.

Comment: P.S. How exactly do I go over this? I'm clueless... can you provide me with a step by step procedure?

Comment: @UrBestFriend A vote up and accepting the answer is good form if you get your answer :)

Comment: @Wes yup but its incomplete... very vague

Comment: @UrBestFriend I just tried to outline what you would do because to fully answer it would not be possible here.  Reading about sphinx/solr should get your started.  I am guessing you already have a web app that is producing the RSS feed so you can interface that to sphinx/solr and then have your flash app post a request to the web app for the search results.